# span message shown at the top of screen

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a span inside that will display a message on a web page. I would like that message to show at top where ever the user is located in page. So lets say that the user is scrolled all the way at the bottom of the page, I would like that message to display to them at the highest point that they can see on the page. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
position:fixed
```

here's a little sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8APrp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `position:fixed` in your css for your div.

Comment: Do you have an example page that I could check out?

Comment: You can look at the differences of static, absolute, fixed and relative here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed The only drawback is doesn't allow you to change the values. But you should get the point.

Comment: In the example to see Fixed in action, you will need to change your browser window very small so that you can scroll and still see the red box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes position: fixed  example here http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but:
    position:fixed
is not supported by all browsers. A better alternative is the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body>
        <div id='top_message'></div>
        <div id='main_container'></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#top_message
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
}

#main_conatainer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: So as you can see, we create 2 containers, 1 for the message div and another for the main content of the website. doing it this way takes longer but it assures compatibility with all browsers and most DOCTYPES